# JQ to parse nested Json

Tags: json, jq, jsonparser

i am trying to extract values for version and filename.

**input.json**

```
[
  {
    "Ver": "1.0",
    "ubuntu": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "filename": "1_0_0.log"
    }
  },
  {
    "Ver": "1.1",
    "ubuntu": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "filename": "1_0_1.log"
    }
  },
  {
    "Ver": "1.4",
    "ubuntu": {
      "version": "1.0.4",
      "filename": "1_0_4.log"
    },
    "centos": {
      "version": "1.0.4",
      "filename": "1_0_4.pdf"
    }
  }
]
```

using

> jq '[.[].centos.version]' input.json
> jq '[.[].ubuntu.version]' input.json

i want to know how this can be done using single command to extract it. something similar to
jq '[.[].*.version]' input.json

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `.[][].version`?

Comment: In the above duplicate, change the field to `version` i.e. `[ getpath ( paths | select( .[-1] == "version" ) ) ]`

Comment: @Inian this works but how can i pull both values like both filename and version. so i can use it in shell script to process further .

Comment: @mebb your question is a little ambiguous as there are many ways to extract multiple values (such as filename and version) at once in jq.  I would suggest editing your question to include an example of the precise output you would like given your sample input.

Comment: @jq170727 what i am expecting is to parse json file so i can print version and filename. so it can be used in other scripts.

**Desired Output.**

`[
{
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "filename": "1_0_0.log"
  },
  {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "filename": "1_0_1.log"
  },
 {
      "version": "1.0.4",
      "filename": "1_0_4.log"
    },
    {
      "version": "1.0.4",
      "filename": "1_0_4.pdf"
    }
]`

Comment: In this specific case you could start with `[ .[][] | select(objects) ]` and add additional filters if you need them. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z9aQS86NjpWoUahODUnNblEIz8pC0gVayrEAiW5FBSqgVhBQSkstUjJSkHJUM9ASQciUppUmldSChSEqACKlKUWFWfm50HVwVUCZdIyc1LzEnNTwVLxBvEGejn56Upg2VogWauDxSJDoi0yxG2RIREWmRBtkQlui0yQLIIal5yaV5JfTK5xBSlpSO7migUA "jq – Try It Online")